# Consuming a .net 2.0 web-service from a DLL without app.config

Tags: dll, .net-2.0, asmx, app-config

General question consuming a .net 2.0 web-service without app.config

Please excuse my bad english:

What I already did:

I wrote an test console application which connects with a preconfigured web-connection that is stored within app.config, this works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="XpageServiceSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="XpageServiceSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www.anydomain.com/XpageService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="XpageServiceSoap"
                contract="XsysService.XpageServiceSoap" name="XpageServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now I wanted to build an assembly which I can also use with COM. Trying to call the DLL Function results in an error, because it's not possible to have a app.config for the DLL.

I would like to have the connection information within my DLL. So I tried the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IXsysService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string userpswd(string user, string passwort);
    [OperationContract]
    string pagesource(string page, string tokenxml, string ip);
}
```

And called from main:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://www.anydomain.com/XpageService.asmx");
WSHttpBinding bind = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
ChannelFactory<IXsysService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IXsysService>(bind, address);
IXsysService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Abruf: {0}", proxy.userpswd("user",GetPasswortFromConsole())); // exception!
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It seems that the proxy connects successfully via SSL. But when calling userpswd() I receive the following exception (translated from German):

"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The request can not be handled without a valid action parameter. Specify a valid SOAPAction object."

When I try this:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://www.anydomain.com/XpageService.asmx?wsdl");
```

I get the same exception.

May be I am completely wrong with what I try.

Does someone have any suggestions how I can solve this problem? I need an assembly that connects to the web-service without any app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Only one config file source is ever used by an application. That is the config file for the application itself. In your case, it's the config for the console application.

All settings must in that file. If they came from the app.config of a DLL, then they need to be copied into the app.config of the console application.

This is because a single library (DLL) may be used by different consuming projects (console applications, Windows Services, desktop applications). Each of these may need the settings to be different. It wouldn't work to have just one set of settings, for the library, ignoring the different users of the library.

Comment: ok, but finally I need a COM assembly that can be used by COM (where is no app.config) and also by .net applycations.

Comment: Then you have to live without settings

Comment: This brings us back to the question: is the shown way to consume the service via SSL ok? If yes, why does the call of userpswd() not work? I didn't find any example for this problem - this is why I think, my Approach is completely wrong.